# How to get an app onto an iPhone without changing the iPhone App Store region?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-appstore

How can I put an app from another region onto an iPhone, but without changing that iPhone's App Store country/region?

Comment: Is this about the store or about your Apple ID? Which problem are you trying to avoid by not switching the region?